# Download File to Roaming Issue

Tags: c++

I am trying to have a file download to My appdata roaming folder but this does not work.

```
  LPCTSTR Url = _T("http://examplesite.com/file.exe"), 
File = ("%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\file.exe");
        hr = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url, File, 0, 0);
```

It does not download it works if I were to do File = ("C:\"); but I need it to download to the roaming folder.

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and that you read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons for down-votes of your question.

Comment: It does not download it works if I were to do File = ("C:\\"); but I need it to download to the roaming folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` to transform `%USERPROFILE%` into something sensible.

Comment: Could you write a example?